# PostgreSQL, unnest array into values

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, unnest

Assuming I have text input:

Buying on Saturday, delivery by XXX, address YYY, payment method ZZZ

Please quote us on prices and stock availability

```
К52-1Б - 68мкф/50в
К52-1 - 100мкф/63в
```

How can I modify this query, so I don't need to split lines manually?

```
with long_string (ls) as (values
    ('Buying on Saturday, delivery by XXX, address YYY, payment method ZZZ'),
    ('Please quote us on prices and stock availability'),
    ('К52-1Б - 68мкф/50в'),
    ('К52-1 - 100мкф/63в')
)
select products.*, matches, similarity
from products
cross join long_string
cross join lateral
(select
    (name % ls)::int as matches,
    similarity(name, ls) as similarity
) m
where matches > 0 and similarity > 0.7
order by matches desc, similarity desc;
```

I tried

```
with long_string (ls) as (
    values
        unnest(string_to_array('Buying on Saturday, delivery by XXX, address YYY, payment method ZZZ 
        Please quote us on prices and stock availability
        К52-1Б - 68мкф/50в
        К52-1 - 100мкф/63в', '\n'))
    )
select products.*, matches, similarity
....
```

But there is an error `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "unnest"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is just about parsing the string, then:

```
with long_string (ls) as (
    select unnest(string_to_array(str, E'\n'))
    from (values ('Buying on Saturday, delivery by XXX, address YYY, payment method ZZZ 
Please quote us on prices and stock availability
К52-1Б - 68мкф/50в
К52-1 - 100мкф/63в')
         ) v(str)
    )
select ls
from long_string;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=03b220d09b0f54b7ffb7ccaff90dc24b) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do this:

```
with long_string (ls) as (
    select
         trim(regexp_split_to_table('Buying on Saturday, delivery by XXX, address YYY, payment method ZZZ
        Please quote us on prices and stock availability
        К52-1Б - 68мкф/50в
        К52-1 - 100мкф/63в', '\n'))
    )
select *
from long_string
```

Comment: Thank you, Jos, this also works. I gonna accept Gordon's answer, since he was first to reply